# Tab character when exporting in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I issue a query in pgAdmin and then want to export the result to a file. How can I specify that the column separator should be a tab character?

Answer (score 7):

This comes probably too late for you, but maybe not for others.

You can copy / paste a **literal tab character** into the (dropdown) text box for "Column separator", like any other valid character, and it will be used. Just tested successfully with pgAdmin 1.14.2.

Comment: In case people don't know what he means by literal tab character, open notepad, make sure the cursor is in the text area, hit the tab key, select all and copy.  Paste this into the pgadmin text box where you can specify a 'column separator'/delimiter

Answer (score -1):

So far, there is no tab-character option in pgAdmin when you try to export the result to a file.

Refer to: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/export.html

Comment: It is possible to type your own characters into the dropdown menu/text box for the column separator. I am just not sure how to represent a tab there.

Comment: Ok.. By the way, I have seen this site for pgAdmin III v1.6.0 (if this is not the version your using), though, I haven't tried this yet.. http://www.postgresql.org/about/news.685